# If statement inside a for loop to find a function?

Tags: functions, procedural-programming

I am trying to find the value of two functions with two variables by using for loop. Then I want them to satisfy a condition and if that holds then I want to write only those sets of the variables for which the rate just becomes less than exp and then go to the next value. I have tried like this but didn't work. It is printing all those sets for which rate < exp. How can I do that?

```
rate= 0.5 (T^5/rt^4);
exp=10^(-18) T^2;
For[rt=10^3,rt <= 10^5,rt=rt+10
For[T=1,T <= 10^3,T=T+10
Evaluate[exp];
Evaluate[rate];
If[rate < exp, Print[{rt, T}]]
]
]
```

Comment: You are not providing complete code to run what you show. what is `interactionrate` and what is `Hubble`?

Comment: @Nasser I have corrected the question. Thanks.

Comment: [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) doesn't do what you think it does. You almost never need `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
rate = 1/2 (T^5/rt^4);
exp = 10^(-18) T^2;

Assuming[T > 0 && rt > 0,
  Reduce[rate < exp, {T, rt}] // FullSimplify]
(*    rt > 10000 2^(1/4) Sqrt[5] T^(3/4)    *)

% // N
(*    rt > 26591.5 T^(3/4)    *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the numbers you gave, it will take forever to finish. (it is also using `For` loop, which is slow).

I fixed few things to make it run, and changed couple of numbers to make it finish quickly.

It is not recommended to use `For` in Mathematica. But here is your `For` version which now works. Using a functional approach will make it faster. May be someone can make a functional version of this if they like.

```
ClearAll[rate, exp, T, rt];
rate[T_, rt_] := 0.5 (T^5/rt^4);
exp[T_] := 10^(-1) T^2;  (*10^(-18) T^2; makes it grow too slow*)
First@Last@Reap@For[rt = 10^3, rt <= 10^4, rt = rt + 10;
    For[T = 1, T <=10, (*10^3, makes it take very long time*)
     T = T + 10 exp[T];
     If[rate[T, rt] < exp[T],
      Sow[{rt, T}]
      ]
     ]
    ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]